# Why is chart.js ignoring these options and applying defaults to donut chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js2

I am creating a chart.js donut chart, it renders fine but ignores all the custom options and renders with defaults.

```
  var mychart= $('<div class="mychart"></div>').appendTo('#calcResults');
mychart= $('<canvas id="mychart-area"></canvas>').appendTo(PaymentBreakDownChartTotal);

chartColors = {
    red: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
    orange: 'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
    yellow: 'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
    green: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
    blue: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
    purple: 'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
    grey: 'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
};
data = {
    datasets: [{
        data: [50, 70, 30],
        backgroundColor: [
            chartColors.red,
            chartColors.orange,
            chartColors.yellow,
        ],
    }],

    labels: [
        'payment',
        'Other',
        'Blue'
    ],
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    var label = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].label || '';

                    if (label) {
                        label += ': ';
                    }
                    label += Math.round(tooltipItem.yLabel * 100) / 100;
                    return label;
                }
            }
        },
        cutoutPercentage: 90,           
      },    
};
   var  mychart= mychart[0].getContext('2d');

var myDoughnutChart = new Chart( PaymentBreakDownChart, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

Have I made an error in my syntax?
Currently, I can't seem to change the cutoutPercentage and the custom tooltip callback is not applied.

Comment: Your `Chart()` initialization references `options`, but it looks like that should be `data.options`?

Comment: Yeah I just realised I had defined options within data.
I need to declare it as options= {blah, blah, blah}